# Bash - echo array length is longer than it actually is

Tags: arrays, bash, echo

```
filesOkay=($(grep -r --include='*.conf' 'mssfix 1372'))
echo files in array - ${#filesOkay[@]}
     f in ${filesOkay[@]}; do 
     echo $f        
done;
```

I have 32 files in a directory that I grep into an array.

The first echo tells me that the length is 62 (why?)

The second echo which iterates through the array and echo's each object correctly identifies all 32 file names.

Have I got confused with the way bash counts array items?

---

Edit :

Thanks to comments for letting me know how to diagnose the issue. It appears that grep is splitting the returns into 2 items in the array for some reason.

The array is showing:
[0]="{file location}:mssfix"
[1]="1372"

I don't want it capture the 1372, and even if I just grep for "mssfix" it still captures and stores the 1372

Is this a grep feature

Cheers

Comment: As always when debugging a shell script, start with https://shellcheck.net

Comment: What does `declare -p filesOkay` show?

Comment: Using an unquoted command substitution like `$(grep ...)` tends to cause problems -- it gets split into *words* (not lines or anything useful), and any words that have anything that looks like a filename wildcard will get expanded into a list of matching files. There are all sorts of things that can go wrong here. If you want to store it in an array by line, use something like `readarray -t filesOkay < <(grep ...)`